# Removing values form DataFrame based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It's necessary to emphasize that it's not about removing rows.

In a simple case I have a file from a sensor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['15/03/2019 10:00:11.000', '15/03/2019 10:00:12.000' , '15/03/2019 10:00:13.000'],
'Pressure' : [-0.162, -0.162, 1.456],
'Conductivity': [-0.001, -0.001, 7.45],
'Water_Temperature': [7.555, 7.555, 8.22],
'Water_Salinity': [0.004, 0.004, 7.63]})
```

I need to remove values in rows where **'Pressure' <1** , the best without removing 'Date' (an information about amount of missing values and incorrect data is also important).

I tried to do it with .where method:

```
condition = df['Pressure'] < 1
droped_df = df.where(condition ," " )
```

but it did nothing. 
Also I don't know how to extend the condition to rest of columns, especially if in the original file there are more.

The resulting effect should looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['15/03/2019 10:00:11.000', '15/03/2019 10:00:12.000' , '15/03/2019 10:00:13.000'],
'Pressure' : [ ,  , 1.456],
'Conductivity': [ ,  , 7.45],
'Water_Temperature': [ ,  , 8.22],
'Water_Salinity': [ ,  , 7.63]})
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for set all columns without first selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) by condition:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mask(df['Pressure'] < 1) 
print (df)
                      Date  Pressure  Conductivity  Water_Temperature  \
0  15/03/2019 10:00:11.000       NaN           NaN                NaN   
1  15/03/2019 10:00:12.000       NaN           NaN                NaN   
2  15/03/2019 10:00:13.000     1.456          7.45               8.22   

   Water_Salinity  
0             NaN  
1             NaN  
2            7.63
```

If really need empty spaces - get mixed values numeric with strings, so all numeric operations failed:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mask(df['Pressure'] < 1, '') 
print (df)
                      Date Pressure Conductivity Water_Temperature  \
0  15/03/2019 10:00:11.000                                           
1  15/03/2019 10:00:12.000                                           
2  15/03/2019 10:00:13.000    1.456         7.45              8.22   

  Water_Salinity  
0                 
1                 
2           7.63
```